# Chrome extension css won't load instantly

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a Chrome extension that injects a javascript file into a page to change the css at all times. When I go to the website, the modified css always takes a fraction of a second longer to load after the page loads. This might create a bad user experience. I'm not sure if this is possible, but I would like to have it change the css and potentially execute other scripts before the user even sees the page.

Manifest file:

```json
{
    "name": "Some Extension",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Some desription",

    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "css": ["styles.css"],
            "js": ["script.js"],
            "matches": ["https://*.familysearch.org/*"]
        }
    ],
    "manifest_version": 2
}
```

script.js

```js
    console.log("Extension working");
    let navElement = document.getElementById('primaryNav');
    navElement.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
```

Comment: Please post your `styles.css`

Comment: My styles.css is empty

Answer (score 2):

[By default extensions are loaded into a page when the browser *feels like it*](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/content_scripts/#run_time) (`run_at: 'document_idle'`) rather than immediately before the page is loaded (`document_start`) or immediately before it finishes loading (`document_end`). Note that these events are unrelated to DOM's `load` and `DOMContentLoaded` events.

You need to do two things:

1. Add `"run_at": 'document_start'` to your extensions' manifest.
2. Update your script so it will work *before* the DOM is loaded (because `document.getElementById('primaryNav')` will return `null` because the `primaryNav` element won't exist yet).

   - [I recommend using `MutationObserver` for this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

Comment: Thanks for recommending the MutationObserver! It looks promising. Could you maybe show me some code of how to use it to add a div as a child to the #primaryNav element once that element loads?